# 'Obtrusive' overlay in PhpStorm on Mac

Tags: macos, phpstorm

This is happening me in PhpStorm on Mac (Sierra), when I go to `File > Preferences`

The problem is best explained with the screenshot linked to below. Notice the light grey square with the red border. I've just pressed a button/link that has a shortcut of <kbd>Shift + F6</kbd>. After pressing this button (using my mouse) an overlay appears, telling me the shortcut.

How do I get rid of this overlay?

[image]

Comment: Does it happen in PhpStorm only? if so -- could be **Key promoter plugin** -- please disable it.

Comment: Thank you @LazyOne , your suggestion solved my problem :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it happens in PhpStorm only then it must be a **Key promoter plugin** -- every time you are invoking an action using your mouse it shows you some sort of "reminder popup" that informs that the same result can be achieved a bit faster using keyboard shortcut.

You may disable that plugin in `Preferences | Plugins`.